# React native detect end of long press

Tags: react-native, touch

My problem is pretty simple, i'm trying to detect the end of a onLongPress event. Basicly when the user release the press.

I'v try every event possible in TouchableWithoutFeedback but there is only one event which is trigger at a time.

```js
import React from 'react'

import {
 View,
 Text,
 Dimensions,
 CameraRoll
} from 'react-native'

import Camera from 'react-native-camera';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')
class ImageBrowser extends React.Component {
 static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Unsplash Images',
 }

 state = {
  images: [],
  loading: true,
  page: 1,
  isRecording : false
 }

 takeVideo(){
  this._recordVideo.bind(this);
 }

 _recordVideo(){
  this.camera.capture({mode: Camera.constants.CaptureMode.video})
   .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
   })
   .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
   })
 }

 _stopRecord(){
  this.camera.stopCapture();
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <Camera
     ref={(cam) => {this.camera = cam;}}
     style={styles.preview}
     aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}
     type={Camera.constants.Type.front}
    >
     <Text style={styles.capture} onLongPress={this.takeVideo.bind(this)} onPress={this._stopRecord.bind(this)} onPressOut={this._stopRecord.bind(this)}>[CAPTURE]</Text>
    </Camera>
   </View>
  )
 }
}

const styles = {
 preview: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  alignItems: 'center',
  height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
  width: Dimensions.get('window').width
 },
 capture: {
  flex: 0,
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  borderRadius: 5,
  color: '#000',
  padding: 10,
  margin: 40
 }
}

export default ImageBrowser
```

Comment: Share your code for check the functionality

Comment: @arunkumar edited

Answer (score 15):

Use Touch*** Component

`onPressIn`

`onPressOut`

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html

Comment: This was what I was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

A better solution is to apply @yongqian_iOS's suggestion and do:

```
<TouchableOpacity
   onPressOut={ () => console.warn('ENDED') }
   onLongPress={ () => console.warn('STARTED LONG PRESS') } 
/>
```

Comment: onPressIn can be used for hold.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question. I finaly used [Gesture Responder](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system.html)

onStartShouldSetResponder => Detect when the user start pressing the element onResponderRelease => Detect when the user stop pressing the element

Here's an example from the official docs using [PanResponder](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder) to make a View ingest gestures:

```
class ExampleComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        // Ask to be the responder:
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,

        onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
          // The gesture has started. Show visual feedback so the user knows
          // what is happening!

          // gestureState.d{x,y} will be set to zero now
        },
        onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
          // The most recent move distance is gestureState.move{X,Y}

          // The accumulated gesture distance since becoming responder is
          // gestureState.d{x,y}
        },
        onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
          // The user has released all touches while this view is the
          // responder. This typically means a gesture has succeeded
        },
        onPanResponderTerminate: (evt, gestureState) => {
          // Another component has become the responder, so this gesture
          // should be cancelled
        },
        onShouldBlockNativeResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
          // Returns whether this component should block native components from becoming the JS
          // responder. Returns true by default. Is currently only supported on android.
          return true;
        },
      });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <View {...this._panResponder.panHandlers} />
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you share a piece of your code? It would be helpful to see how you solved this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question, but it came up in my Google searches when I was trying to solve a similar issue. For future readers, here is how I created a button that animates in and out, but only triggers an action when it's not canceled (by dragging a finger away, or scrolling in a parent ScrollView for ex).

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback, Animated } from 'react-native';
// Vector Icons from here ♥‿♥: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default class tomatoButt extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    onPress: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  // No constructors needed! ┌(ㆆ㉨ㆆ)ʃ
  state = {
    animatedTouchScale: new Animated.Value(1),
  }

  animationStep = (toValue, callback, duration) => {
    const { animatedTouchScale } = this.state;
    Animated.timing(animatedTouchScale, {
      toValue,
      duration: duration || 100,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start(callback);
  }

  // Scale the button down when the user "hovers" on it
  handlePressIn = () => this.animationStep(0.95);

  // Always scale out again, regardless if the touch is cancelled
  handlePressOut = () => this.animationStep(1);

  // If the user taps without holding, then animate in, trigger onPress, and animate out
  handlePress = () => {
    // onPress is an external function. Ex:
    // () => Alert.alert("Don't stop... (づ｡◕‿‿◕｡)づ")
    const { onPress } = this.props;
    this.animationStep(0.95, () => {
      onPress();
      this.animationStep(1, () => {}, 50);
    }, 50);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
         // Called first, when you first touch
        onPressIn={this.handlePressIn}
         // Called second, regardless if the touch is cancelled
        onPressOut={this.handlePressOut}
         // Called last, only when touch is released, but not if it's cancelled
        onPress={this.handlePress}
      >
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            // We'll scale the button down on touches:
            transform: [{ scale: animatedTouchScale }],
            // You should move these styles to an external sheet:
            backgroundColor: 'tomato',
            width: '100%',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            borderRadius: 5,
            padding: 20,
            marginTop: 1,
            marginBottom: 1,
          }}
        >
          {/* Plus icon, OS independent */}
          <Feather
            name="plus"
            size={18}
            color="white"
          />
        </Animated.View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `onPressIn` and `onPressOut` methods to capture the start and end of touch event. `onPressIn` callback is invoked when the user touches the component and `onPressOut` will trigger when the user release the touch.

```
<TouchableOpacity
   onPressIn={ () => console.warn('Touch started') }
   onPressOut={ () => console.warn('Touch ended') } 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onPanResponderRelease: (e, gestureState) => {
        Animated.timing(this.state.visible, {
            toValue: 0,
            duration: 200,
            useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start();
    },
}
```